# Rails RSpec with Apivore for Swagger Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, swagger

I am trying to setup the Apivore Gem to test Swagger documentation on my API. But I am having little difficult to understand how to send content into the body as a JSON.

> Swagger Documentation

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: "api-test-env"
  title: 'Prototype API'
  description: 'Testing out Swagger and building a proof of concept.'
host: virtserver.swaggerhub.com
schemes:
 - https
produces:
  - application/json
securityDefinitions:
  Bearer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header

paths:
  /oauth/token:
    post:
      consumes: 
        - application/json
      tags: 
        - Account
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: Credentials
          description: 'User login'
          schema: 
            type: object
            required: 
              - grant_type
              - username
              - password
            properties:
              grant_type:
                type: string
              username:
                type: string
              password:
                type: string

      responses:
        200:
          description: 'User logged in successfully'
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              access_token:
                type: string
                description: 'Authorization access token'
                example: '0ee0e77afbdd6fcaa0920a0416d5043aee9a21ca75920cda7d2b1be0d9f40885'
              token_type: 
                type: string
                description: 'Authorization token type'
                example: 'Bearer'
              expires_in:
                type: integer
                description: 'Timestamp expiration time'
                example: 3600
              refresh_token:
                type: string
                description: 'Refresh authorization token'
                example: 'ed1307dde23acbb440d6f31520f7d3c8de099e72b04eb1542008ca139fca6364'
              created_at:
                type: integer
                description: 'Timestamp created at time'
                example: 1519312812
```

> RSpec with Apivore Test

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'the API', type: :apivore, order: :defined, focus: true do
  subject { Apivore::SwaggerChecker.instance_for('/docs/swagger.json') }

  context 'has valid paths' do
    Fabricate(:user, email: 'test@email.com', password: 'abc123', password_confirmation: 'abc123')

    let(:credentials) { { 'grant_type' => 'password', 'username' => 'test@email.com', 'password' => 'abc123' } }

    let(:params) do
      {
        '_headers' => { 'accept' => 'application/json', 'content-type' => 'application/json' },
        '_data' => credentials.to_json
      }
    end

    specify do
      expect(subject).to validate(
        :post, '/oauth/token', 200, params
      )
    end
  end

  context 'and' do
    it 'tests all documented routes' do
      expect(subject).to validate_all_paths
    end
  end
end
```

> Error message

```
Failures:

  1) the API has valid paths should validate that post /oauth/token returns 200
     Failure/Error: expect(subject).to validate(
       Path /oauth/token did not respond with expected status code. Expected 200 got 401
       Response body:
        {
         "error": "invalid_grant",
         "error_description": "The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."
       }
     # ./spec/requests/api_swagger_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But I tried to get the token using Postman and worked. This error message happens if the credentials content or the credentials keys are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue just need to replace this line from...

```
Fabricate(:user, email: 'test@email.com', password: 'abc123', password_confirmation: 'abc123')
```

... to

```
let!(:user) { Fabricate(:user, email: 'test@example.com', password: 'abc123', password_confirmation: 'abc123') }
```

this way it will save the persist the user in the database.